# I am trying to run AVD with react-native, but an unknown variable error appears

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run the code created through react-native as AVD in android studio, but I am getting an error about the variable JAVA_HOME. What should I do?

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we need to manually set the path (environment) of `JAVA_JDK` . Install latest JAVA JDK from official website. And set the path of jre and bin folder. After looking your directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` I guess you are on windows , So I'm not sure how to set environment variable for windows but definitely you could get help from youtube.